# Separate first page and keep title and author information

Tags: titles, templates

The editor asks to isolate the title and author information on the first page. The second page starts with the abstract and keywords.

Quote from the author policy stating the requirement:

> "It is mandatory that the full names, full affiliation with country and email address of every contributing author must be included in title (authorship) page of the manuscript. The first page of the manuscript should have the title of the paper, and the full name, full affiliation with country and email address of every contributing author. The second page of the manuscript should begin with the abstract. Note: Cover letter is not title/authorship page."

I'm using the template (Elsevier’s CAS LaTeX Double-Column Template), and below is a reduced working example:

```
%% 
%% Copyright 2019-2020 Elsevier Ltd
%% 
%% This file is part of the 'CAS Bundle'.
%% --------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'CAS Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%% 
%% Template article for cas-dc documentclass for 
%% double column output.

% \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-dc}
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

%%%Author definitions
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}
%%%


\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

% Short title
\shorttitle{Leveraging social media news}

% Short author
\shortauthors{CV Radhakrishnan et~al.}

% Main title of the paper
\title [mode = title]{This is a specimen $a_b$ title}                      
% Title footnote mark
% eg: \tnotemark[1]
\tnotemark[1,2]

% Title footnote 1.
% eg: \tnotetext[1]{Title footnote text}
% \tnotetext[<tnote number>]{<tnote text>} 
\tnotetext[1]{This document is the results of the research
   project funded by the National Science Foundation.}

\tnotetext[2]{The second title footnote which is a longer text matter
   to fill through the whole text width and overflow into
   another line in the footnotes area of the first page.}


\author[1,3]{CV Radhakrishnan}[type=editor,
                        auid=000,bioid=1,
                        prefix=Sir,
                        role=Researcher,
                        orcid=0000-0001-7511-2910]

% Corresponding author indication
\cormark[1]

% Footnote of the first author
\fnmark[1]

% Email id of the first author
\ead{cvr_1@tug.org.in}

% URL of the first author
\ead[url]{www.cvr.cc, cvr@sayahna.org}

%  Credit authorship
\credit{Conceptualization of this study, Methodology, Software}

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[1]{organization={Elsevier B.V.},
    addressline={Radarweg 29}, 
    city={Amsterdam},
    % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
    postcode={1043 NX}, 
    % state={},
    country={The Netherlands}}

% Second author
\author[2,4]{Han Theh Thanh}[style=chinese]

% Third author
\author[2,3]{CV Rajagopal}[%
   role=Co-ordinator,
   suffix=Jr,
   ]
\fnmark[2]
\ead{cvr3@sayahna.org}
\ead[URL]{www.sayahna.org}

\credit{Data curation, Writing - Original draft preparation}

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[2]{organization={Sayahna Foundation},
    % addressline={}, 
    city={Jagathy},
    % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
    postcode={695014}, 
    state={Trivandrum},
    country={India}}

% Fourth author
\author%
[1,3]
{Rishi T.}
\cormark[2]
\fnmark[1,3]
\ead{rishi@stmdocs.in}
\ead[URL]{www.stmdocs.in}

\affiliation[3]{organization={STM Document Engineering Pvt Ltd.},
    addressline={Mepukada}, 
    city={Malayinkil},
    % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
    postcode={695571}, 
    state={Trivandrum},
    country={India}}

% Corresponding author text
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author}

% Footnote text
\fntext[fn1]{This is the first author footnote. but is common to third
  author as well.}
\fntext[fn2]{Another author footnote, this is a very long footnote and
  it should be a really long footnote. But this footnote is not yet
  sufficiently long enough to make two lines of footnote text.}

% For a title note without a number/mark
\nonumnote{This note has no numbers. In this work we demonstrate $a_b$
  the formation Y\_1 of a new type of polariton on the interface
  between a cuprous oxide slab and a polystyrene micro-sphere placed
  on the slab.
  }

% Here goes the abstract
\begin{abstract}
This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.

\noindent\texttt{\textbackslash begin{abstract}} \dots 
\texttt{\textbackslash end{abstract}} and
\verb+\begin{keyword}+ \verb+...+ \verb+\end{keyword}+ 
which
contain the abstract and keywords respectively. 

\noindent Each keyword shall be separated by a \verb+\sep+ command.
\end{abstract}

% Use if graphical abstract is present
% \begin{graphicalabstract}
% \includegraphics{figs/grabs.pdf}
% \end{graphicalabstract}

% Keywords
% Each keyword is seperated by \sep
\begin{keywords}
quadrupole exciton \sep polariton \sep \WGM \sep \BEC
\end{keywords}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
...


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE @kosmos :) Do you have more information about what the editor wants? Should the author(s) be on another page or another column or did you mean "separate" with a bigger spacing? Also, does the editor uses LaTeX (and that template) or are they your own choice(s)?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. 
I quote from the editor: "It is mandatory that the full names, full affiliation with country and email address of every contributing author must be included in title (authorship) page of the manuscript. The first page of the manuscript should have the title of the paper, and the full name, full affiliation with country and email address of every contributing author. The second page of the manuscript should begin with the abstract.  Note: Cover letter is not title/authorship page."
I do not know if the editor uses LaTeX. The template is my choice.

Comment: That's clearer. I think you should edit the question to add the quote. It provides some hints for answers that will be write down.

Comment: Thank @gildux for the suggestion. I’ve already done just that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it means you can't just use `\maketitle` but have to use the `titlepage` environment to make custom one. See [this overleaf page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_5)%3A_Customising_Your_Title_Page_and_Abstract), for example, as starting point. I'll edit my answer a bit later with an MWE based on yours.